# how to set up an image across lines

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to put a single image along the details.The result is like

```
Line1   |      |
line2   |      |
line3   |Image | 
Line4   |      |
Line5   |      |
```

Now I put the Image in the detail section and set display restraint to first line. But it display like

```
        |      |
        |      |
line1   |Image | 
        |      |
        |      |
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Anyone know how to do it? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a subreport.

Create a new subreport that will list the lines that currently are in the details section.

Put it besides the image:

[subreport] [image]

Move them to the report header (or group header depending on how you work your data).